# Nokogiri - Get div with class by regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri gem on my rails application to get some html nodes. I'm getting my div by its class. But that class name will change sometimes. For example, right now I'm getting it like this:

```
doc.css("div.t.m0.x15.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1")
```

but that "x15" can be "x13", for example. I could do something like this:

```
doc.css("div.t.m0.x13.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1", "div.t.m0.x15.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1")
```

This would work, but I think it would be nicer to set a range, like x13-x15, so if it comes a x14, I don't need to keep it so verbose.

Any tips of how to do that? Thanks!

EDIT:

I can't remove the "x*" class, 'cause there's another div with the same another classes, so what differences the two elements is the "x" class. The another one is xa, xb; and this one I'm trying to get is x13, x15.

Comment: could you not do `doc.css("div.t.m0.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1")` (without the `x13` or `x15`) and then check if the selected element also has an `x\d\d` class?

Comment: Maybe you can target the div with a selector that is not affected by the change? How does your markup look like? Why does the class change? _"x15 can be x13"_ seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: Can't do that guys, updated the question. There's another element I would get if I remove the x* class

Comment: I never used Nokogiri but can't you do `classes_to_select = ['.x15', '.x13']` and then `doc.css(*classes_to_select.map { |c| "div#{base_classes}#{c}" })`? where `base_classes = '.t.m0.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1'`

Comment: @MrYoshiji yeah, that would be a good option. But would like to know first if there's some way to do that with regex. In case not, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @MrYoshiji You can post your answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.xpath` method for that purpose. E.g.

```
doc.xpath("//div[@class='x13' or @class='x15']")
```

Or you can use

```
//div[starts-with(@class, 'x') and (ends-with(@class, '13') or (ends-with(@class, '15'))]
```

Searching by regexp appears in XPath 2.0, but I don't know what xpath version nokogiri supports.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need regex you would use `select`:

```
doc.css("div.t.m0.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1").
  select{|div| div[:class][/x1[3-5]/]}
```

Note: that regex may not do what you expect. Also note: using `select` turns your NodeSet into an Array

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
base_classes = '.t.m0.h3.ff2.fs1.fc0.sc0.ls0.ws1'
extra_classes = ['.x15', '.x13']
doc.css(*extra_classes.map { |extra_class| "div#{base_classes}#{extra_class}" })
```